# Where is the lombok source code responsible for implementing the annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I was browsing the source [code](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/AllArgsConstructor.java) of the Lombok project, as I'm learning about Annotations and AOP in general and I thought that would be a good example to draw inspiration from.

However, I don't understand, the `AllArgsConstructor` only defines the annotation - that part I get from what I grasped so far - but where is the code that actually adds the constructor ? And all other annotations.

Comment: Compile time annotation pre-processor, is the query that you need to search for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first note that if you want to learn about annotation processing, Lombok is *not* a good example to start with. Lombok is not a regular annotation processor (which only adds new source files to the compilation). Instead, it modifies existing Java sources. That is not what annotation processors typically do, and it's not something the annotation processing in `javac` was designed for. Lombok uses the API of `javac` to modify and enrich an abstract syntax tree. That makes it complex and difficult to understand.

To answer your question, the logic that generates the code for Lombok annotations is located in so-called handlers. In your case, it's the `HandleConstructor` classes (there are two of them: [one for `javac`](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleConstructor.java), [one for the Eclipse compiler](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/eclipse/handlers/HandleConstructor.java)).